# Unity cannot find named component when assembly is built with optimize setting

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm having a strange issue with Unity not resolving my named instance when I build my solution in Release configuration with the optimize code setting checked.

I've enabled fusion logging and it doesn't seem to be an assembly binding issue.

I've opened the compiled assembly using a decompiler and the class seems to be there so it;s not being optimised out because it's not referenced anywhere.

The assembly reference seems okay because my application doesn't throw any errors when it's trying to register the class with the container.

I'm not sure what else to check.

This is how I register the dependencies.

```
// these updaters are one assembly with lots of other code, they're resolved okay
Container.RegisterType<IClientUpdater, MayriseUpdater>("Client1");
Container.RegisterType<IClientUpdater, MayriseUpdater>("Client2");
// this updater is in an assembly with nothing else in it 
Container.RegisterType<IClientUpdater, RutlandUpdater>("Client3");
```

This is how they are resolved

```
updater = this._container.Resolve<IClientUpdater>(client.Name);
```

A few last things to add, this only seems to happen in IIS. IIS Express seems to work fine.

I do get an assembly binding error for an assembly which the RutlandUpdater depends on but the MayriseUpdater also depends on the same one and works okay so I think this might be a red herring.

Comment: What version of Unity you using?

Comment: I'm using the following Nuget packages Unity 3.5.1404.0, Unity.Mvc 3.5.1404.0 and  Unity.Wcf 1.0

Comment: That didn't work out quite as well as I'd like.